# Approximating a multiple sum with an integral

Tags: asymptotics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

Hi,

I want to approximate a multiple sum of the form
$$\sum_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m \leq n}e^{g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)},$$
where each $x_i$ is an integer between $0$ and $n$,
by an integral
$$\int_{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m \leq n}e^{g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)}dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_m\,.$$
I know that the Euler-Maclaurin formula can be used to derive the error term when $m=1$ but often see sums of this form with $m > 1$ approximated by integrals, though with little justification. I do not have much of a background in mathematical analysis so am not sure where to look for a reference for this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In fact Euler-Maclaurin applies to your case as well. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10667/

Comment: First of all, for a "generic" function $g$ your approximation by sum can be really bad. There are different techniques in asymptotic analysis (including Euler-Maclaurin) which can be used for your sums.

Answer (score 2):

See Chapter 10 of [*Computing the Continuous Discretely*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tofDpuuEDu4C&lpg=PR1&pg=PA166) by Beck and Robins for an introduction, and the paper of Brion and Vergne cited in the link in my comment for the general case.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Looks like a very interesting book.
BTW, the google books view is limited but there's actually a full, non-printable, .pdf on the author's website
http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/ccd.html